# Why won't Chrome load extension with Content Security Policy that allows localhost?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm working on a Chrome extension and wanted to load scripts from `localhost` for development. So I updated the manifest file to have the following line:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost; object-src 'self'",
```

According to the doc on [Content Security Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-remote-script), it's perfectly fine to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` without `https`.

However, I get the following (taunting) error message when I try to load the extension from `chrome://chrome/extensions/`:

> Could not load extension from '/Users/Tim/Desktop/temp/test'. Invalid value for 'content_security_policy': Both 'script-src' and 'object-src' directives must be specified (either explicitly, or implicitly via 'default-src'), and both must whitelist only secure resources. You may include any of the following sources: "'self'", "'unsafe-eval'", "http://127.0.0.1", "http://localhost", or any "https://" or "chrome-extension://" origin. For more information, see http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

To confirm the problem, you can create an empty directory with the following `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "Example extension",
  "description": "Trying to demonstrate a bug in Chrome",
  "version": "0.1",
  "homepage_url": "http://example.com",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost; object-src 'self'",

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

and load the directory as an unpacked extension. You should be getting the error. If you remove `http://localhost` or change it to `https://localhost`, it will load fine.

Am I missing something?

(NB: I'm using Chrome 22.0.1229.79)

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the example works fine in Chrome Canary (24.0.1280.0), so I'm guessing it's a bug that was fixed and will come to "normal" Chrome eventually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability to add `localhost` to the CSP value was enabled by [Chromium revision 151470](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?view=rev&revision=151470), which is in Chrome 23 (currently in the dev channel, soon to be in the beta channel).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! I guess the problem is that the documentation and the error message are ahead of their time, creating confusion for me. I just serve my files on https in the meantime :) (it's just for dev purposes anyway)

Comment: 9 years past, this issue occured again. though the official doc says we can use localhost. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#content-security-policy